# Object reference not set to an instance of an object exception when assigning a list to a listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, list, nullreferenceexception

I wrote the following method to load a list box with values that have not been loaded already but I am getting an Object reference not set to an instance of an object exception when assigning the following. Any information would be helpful. Thanks.

```
lbxCabinetName.Items.Add(cabinetsCurrentNotUsed[i].ToString());

// Defined outside a method
List<string> cabinetsCurrentNotUsed; 

// Set value in the constructor
cabinetsCurrentNotUsed = new List<string>();
```

Here is the whole procedure.

```
    private void selectCabinetToAdd()
    {

        // Loop through all server and form cabinet types to see if there are matches
        for (int x = 0; x < opticalFile.serverCabinetNames.Count; x++)
        {
            bool cabinetExists = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < opticalFile.CabinetValues.Count; i++)
            {
                if (opticalFile.serverCabinetNames[x].ToString() == opticalFile.CabinetValues[i].ToString())
                {
                    cabinetExists = true;
                }
            }
            // Add cabinets not used to cabinetsCurrentNotUsed List
            if (!cabinetExists)
            {
                cabinetsCurrentNotUsed.Add(opticalFile.serverCabinetNames[x].ToString());
            }
        }

        // Send cabinetsCurrentNotUsed List to list box
        for (int i = 0; i < cabinetsCurrentNotUsed.Count; i++)
        {
            lbxCabinetName.Items.Add(cabinetsCurrentNotUsed[i].ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is it possible *lbxCabinetName* is null?  That's the only possibility I can see.

Comment: That is possible but isn't that the point of adding items? How do I make sure the lbxCabinetName list box is not null so I can add an item? Also I removed the .ToString(), I added it hoping for a longshot fix.

Comment: Well, really if your function requires it to be not null, you should put something like this at the beginning of your function: *if (lbxCabinetName == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("lbxCabinetName cannot be null");*

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to add a null to the listbox.

Insted of

```
for (int i = 0; i < cabinetsCurrentNotUsed.Count; i++)
{
     lbxCabinetName.Items.Add(cabinetsCurrentNotUsed[i].ToString());
}
```

use

```
foreach (string s in cabinetsCurrentNotUsed)
{
    if(s != null)
          lbxCabinetName.Items.Add(s);
}
```

**NOTE**

This part is not relavant to the question. But in your inner for loop after setting `cabinetExists = true;` you can break out of the inner loop (if atleast one condition is met you can make sure the cabinetExists is true. you don't have to check for the rest of the items in the inner loop)

**EDIT**

```
private void selectCabinetToAdd()
{
        foreach (string sc in serverCabinetNames)
        {
            bool cabinetExists = false;
            foreach (string cv in CabinetValues)
            {
                if (sc == cv)
                {
                    cabinetExists = true;
                    break;
                }                    
            }

            if (!cabinetExists)
            {
                cabinetsCurrentNotUsed.Add(sc);
            }

        }

        foreach (string ccnu in cabinetsCurrentNotUsed)
        {
            if (ccnu != null)
                lbxCabinetName.Items.Add(ccnu);
        }
   }
```

Also if your listBox can be null, make sure you check that first before populating the listbox.

```
if(lbxCabinetName != null)
{
    selectCabinetToAdd();
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Dynamically adding control

```
ListBox lbxCabinetName = new ListBox();
lbxCabinetName.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 55);
lbxCabinetName.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(130, 95);
this.Controls.Add(lbxCabinetName);
```

Comment: I used this exact code and I still get the same error. I know the list is not null. Also it throws the exception on the first iteration of the loop.

Comment: I am running the debug and it does state that lbxCabinetName listbox is null. How do I set it to not be null? I thought adding an item is susposed to make it not null.

Comment: @JoBaxter how are you adding the listbox? dynamically or through the designer

Comment: @JoBaxter I edited my post. Now you should not get exception in the iteration loop

Comment: @dbaseman in the beginning details provided by OP was not very clear. Anyway I modified my code.

Comment: I am adding it dynamically. I added if (s != null && lbxCabinetName != null)  and it doesn't throw an exception but since the listbox is always null it doesn't load anything now.

Comment: @JoBaxter there is obviously something wrong with the way you dynamically add the control. Check my EDIT 2 in post. BTW: it is hard to provide a solution without seeing your code or stack trace on exception.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm adding it through the designer. Also I've gotten it down to the list box being the issue. Something is causing it to be null so no items can be added.

Comment: I just found the issue. The method call was in the constructor. I moved it into the form load and everything is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are nullable so at some point you must be doing something similar to:

```
cabinetsCurrentNotUsed.Add(null);
```

Either that or as dbaseman said it is possible `lbxCabinetName` is null but I'm betting that isn't the case.

As an aside, it's not really a problem but if you're using a generic list of strings the `ToString()` call isn't necessary. You can just do this:

```
lbxCabinetName.Items.Add(cabinetsCurrentNotUsed[i]);
```